# How can I set the initial values with my Factorial Assembly code?

Tags: assembly, mips, factorial, mars-simulator

here is my original code

```
main:    
    addi $sp, $sp, -8   # adjust stack for 2 items
    sw $ra, 4($sp)      # save return address
    sw $a0, 0($sp)      # save argument
    slti $t0, $a0, 1    # test for n<1
    beq $t0, $zero, L1
    addi $v0, $zero, 1  # if so, result is 1
    addi $sp, $sp, 8    # pop 2 items from stack
    jr $ra          # and return
L1: addi $a0, $a0, -1   # else decrement n
    jal main        # recursive call
    lw $a0, 0($sp)      # restore original n
    lw $ra, 4($sp)      # and return address
    addi $sp, $sp, 8    # pop 2 items from stack
    mul $v0, $a0, $v0   # multiply to get result
    jr $ra          # and return
```

I want the initial value for `n!` which is `n=2, $sp <= 0x0000 A0000`

Comment: not sure what you are asking, maybe you may want to move your current code into some procedure like `factorial:` (basically just renaming `main`), and create new `main`, which will set `a0` to initial value (2?), a do `jal factorial` and then it will use the MARS syscall to terminate (v0=10 I think from head). Do you mean this?

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions by removing all the code.  That makes them meaningless / harder to understand.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, Sorry, my professor asked me to delete it. Because it's part of a assignment and other students could copy it without trying to solve... I tried to delete the question but I couldn't. Sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate function that you call *from* `main`, instead of making `main` itself recursive.

---

Or use the first arg of `int main(int argc, char **argv)` as `n`.

So you'd run your program with `./fac $(seq 2 4)` to run it with `$a0 = 4`.  [What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

The Unix `seq 2 4` command prints `2 3 4`, so the command has 3 arguments plus the implicit first arg (the command name), thus the C startup code will pass `4` to `main` as the `argc` argument.

Using `./foo $(seq  number)` is a convenient hack for messing around with hand-written asm, to avoid writing int-parsing code and have your program start with a binary integer already in a register (or in memory on some other platforms, like `_start` instead of `main` in the x86-64 System V ABI).